# Opening app in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbs code below

```
strComputer = "."
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set wmiEvent = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery("select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity' and TargetInstance.Description='USB Mass Storage  Device'")
While True
Set usb = wmiEvent.NextEvent()
if usb.Path_.Class = "__InstanceCreationEvent" then WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "msgHello.bat",0,True
Wend
```

It doesn't open the .bat file as I want it to, I do not no how to fix it. Plz help me!

Comment: Define "as I want it to".

Comment: Just an FYI, there's a double space in `'USB Mass Storage  Device'` which could cause a query failure against the win32_pnpentity

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not running?  You currently have it set to hide the command prompt window because of the `0` in the `.Run "msgHello.bat",0,True` call.  Try setting it to `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: I want to set it to hide the cmd. Even though I've set it to normal screen, it doesn't work

Comment: Add a `pause` statement to the last line of your BAT file and set the 2nd param of `Run` back to a 1 and see if the window appears (and stays).